# Remapping special/function keys on new keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, keyboard-layout

I currently have Ubuntu 22.04 set up on my laptop, and sometimes I plug my laptop into a second monitor and use a second keyboard. I would like to be able to seamlessly change my keyboard layout based on the keyboard in use, since my second keyboard has certain keys remapped. I see the best way of easily changing between keyboards to be `super` + `space` keystroke, but I'm stuck on how to actually get a second keyboard layout.

I would basically like to remap my special keys, i.e. my function keys. On my laptop, the volume up and volume down keys are under `f2` and `f3`, but on my second keyboard, they're under `f11` and `f12`. I saw other questions asked and answered that say to go into settings and remap the keys from there, but that would be relatively hard to change on the fly, and I think having two separate custom keyboard layouts would be better. I just don't know how to easily set up a second custom keyboard layout based on QWERTY US English layout.

Thanks!

Comment: With apologies on behalf of the community, it looks like your question was spammed by a trio of bots that are posting multiple AI-generated answers on questions. Unfortunately, the majority of the Moderators on Stack Exchange sites (including Ask Ubuntu) are on strike *primarily* because the parent company has reduced their ability to remove these bogus answers.  We're hoping that things get back to normal shortly, but in the meantime, we're having to deal with stuff like this.

Comment: At some point, the AI-generated answers below will be removed, so it's possible they'll already be gone by the time you check back in here. In that case, you'll just be thoroughly confused on what I'm talking about ;-).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Wow... hadn't heard about the strike or the Stack Exchange, Inc. decisions, but that really sucks. Something seemed too good to be true when I got three answers back-to-back...

Comment: Out of curiosity, did any of them help? Sometimes the GPT systems get things right, but they are also way to likely to “hallucinate” features and settings that aren’t there sometimes. I’m *guessing* they didn’t help here, based on your “too good to be true” comment :-)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yeah, none of them worked. I feel the answer from ary is probably the most legit, but still didn't work. The other two are completely wrong though. Oh AI...